# Setting Up High-Res Monitor

Tags: nvidia, display-resolution

I have a desktop computer with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and an NVidia GEForce 630 4Gig graphics card.  I was running a monitor at 1900x1200, and just bought a new one that should do 2560x1440.  However, I can't get that higher resolution to work.  With HDMI or VGA cables, the highest resolution offered is 1900x1080.  I've tried increasing it manually with xrandr, with no luck (I get a BadMatch error).

With a DVI cable, it seems as though it wants to come up at the higher resolution, but the colors are all green and very washed out when it first starts.  After a few seconds, it just goes to black.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Richard